# La función HEADER y DEFINE no me redireccionan (No se comunican)

Tags: php, get, define

Mi situación es bastante simple pero por mas que busco no encuentro solucionarlo.
Me encuentro trabajando con XAMPP en la carpeta "htdocs"
Ahí tengo 2 archivos PHP uno que se llama "origen.php" y otro "destino.php"
En el archivo "origen.php" tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
define('DESTINO','destino.php?mensaje=hola_mensaje');
header('Location: '.DESTINO);   
?>
```

Por otra parte en el archivo destino.php tengo este otro codigo:

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
$identificador =$_GET['hola_mensaje'];
?>
```

Lo que necesito es recoger la variable 'hola_mensaje' con el metodo $_GET y meterlo en el identificador pero cuando recargo la pagina http://localhost/destino.php me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> Array ( ) Warning: Undefined array key "hola_mensaje" in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\destino.php on line 3

Es decir no me pasa la variable por el metodo "GET" . No se a que se deba el problema, los 2 archivos estan en la misma carpeta, cambie la sintaxis y sigue sin funcionar por mas que lo intento no puedo (Y mas simple es imposible) simplemente no logro que exista conexión entre los 2 archivo, ¿Alguna idea? Necesito recuperar esa variable "hola_mensaje" .

Comment: "hola_mensaje" es el valor, no el nombre de la variable, en lugar de hacer `$identificador = $_GET['hola_mensaje'];` debes hacer `$identificador = $_GET['mensaje'];`. Dejando eso, ¿realmente necesitas este tipo de comunicación? lo normal es estructurar el código de tal forma que puedas acceder a informacion compartida utilizando `require`, si necesitas persistencia podrías usar _memcache_ o _redis_.

Comment: Creo que casi resolví el problema... (No  del todo porque creo que no había comunicación entre los 2 archivos) sin embargo descubrí lo siguiente.

Si RECARGO en el navegador el archivo "destino.php" me sale el error:

Array ( ) Warning: Undefined array key "hola_mensaje" in D:\xampp\htdocs\destino.php on line 3

Pero si recargo el navegador desde "origen.php" parece que me "REDIRECCIONA" al archivo destino.php y me muestra el ARRAY 

Array ( [mensaje] => hola_mensaje ) hola_mensaje

Me imagino que esto sucede porque cuando recargo "destino.php" no hay AÚN CONEXION y eso era el error

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esto:

```
$identificador =$_GET['hola_mensaje'];
```

Por esto:

```
$identificador =$_GET['mensaje'];
```

El enlace `destino.php?mensaje=hola_mensaje` guarda en la variable `$_GET['mensaje']` el valor "hola_mensaje".

Más información en [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php)

Y para evitar el error:

> Array ( ) Warning: Undefined array key "hola_mensaje" in D:\xampp\htdocs\destino.php on line 3

Usaría:

```
if(isset($_GET['mensaje'])){
  print_r($_GET);
  $identificador = $GET['mensaje'];
}else{
 header('Location: origen.php');
}
```